# python, dynamically implement a class onthefly

Tags: python, function, interface, methods, addition

Assuming i have a class that implements several methods. We want a user to chose to which methods to run among the exisiting methods or he can decide to add any method on_the_fly.

from example

```
class RemoveNoise():
       pass
```

then methods are added as wanted

```
RemoveNoise.raw = Raw()
RemoveNoise.bais = Bias()
etc
```

he can even write a new one

```
def new():
   pass
```

and also add the `new()` method

```
RemoveNoise.new=new
run(RemoveNoise)
```

`run()` is a function that evaluates such a class.

I want to save the class_with_the_methods_used and link this class to the object created.

Any hints on how to solve this in python?

Comment: will multiple users be modifying the same classes? do you also want to modify instances?

Comment: any user can choose which methods he wants or define his own methods

Comment: Explain what you mean with "save" and "link". Are you trying to say that you somehow have persistent objects, and each object can have it's own set of methods? That's perfectly possible (and not even hard) but then you are asking the wrong question. :)

Answer (score 6):

Functions can be added to a class at runtime.

```
class Foo(object):
  pass

def bar(self):
  print 42

Foo.bar = bar
Foo().bar()
```

Comment: damn, i dont know what happened, the actual problem is not mentioned, after a user has selected the methods i need to save the class_with_the_methods_used and link this class to the object created.

Answer (score 2):

There is no solving needed, you just do it. Here is your code, with the small changes needed:

```
class RemoveNoise():
       pass

RemoveNoise.raw = Raw
RemoveNoise.bias = Bias

def new(self):
   pass

RemoveNoise.new=new

instance = RemoveNoise()
```

It's that simple. Python is wonderful.

Why on earth you would need this is beyond me, though.

Comment: Except that the `new()` method is basically uncallable.

Comment: the actual problem was supposed to be how to save the class_with_the_methods_used and link this class to the object created.

Comment: "Save"? "link"? Neither of these make any sense. Your object will know which class it belongs to automatically, you don't have to do any linking. And saving? How? Where?

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's some code that does what I think you're asking for -- although I'm not really sure what you meant by "**save**" when you wrote "I want to save the class_with_the_methods_used". Also note that using an `exec` statement on user input can be *extremely* dangerous if it comes from an untrusted source.

```
import copy

# an empty "template" class
class Generic():
    pass

# predefined functions that create common methods
def Raw():
    def raw(self):
        print 'in Raw method of instance', id(self)
    return raw

def Bias():
    def bias(self):
        print 'in Bias method of instance', id(self)
    return bias

def user_new_function(definition):
    tempdict = {}
    exec definition in tempdict
    return tempdict['new']

# create a new class
RemoveNoise = copy.deepcopy(Generic)
RemoveNoise.__name__ = 'RemoveNoise' # change the class name of the copy

# add a couple of predefined methods
RemoveNoise.raw = Raw()
RemoveNoise.bias = Bias()

# add user defined 'new' method
user_new_def = """\
def new(self):
    print 'in user defined method "new" of instance', id(self)
"""
RemoveNoise.new = user_new_function(user_new_def)

# create and use an instance of dynamically defined class
instance = RemoveNoise()
print 'RemoveNoise instance "{}" created'.format(id(instance))
# RemoveNoise instance "11974736" created
instance.raw()
# in Raw method of instance 11974736
instance.bias()
# in Bias method of instance 11974736
instance.new()
# in user defined method "new" of instance 11974736
```