# python, dynamically implement a class onthefly

Tags: python, methods

this is related to [python, dynamically implement a class onthefly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387847/python-dynamically-implement-a-class-onthefly).

when i restarted my pc, couldnt get back to add comments to the post - below is an example to explain what meant by save the class_with_the_methods_used

```
class bank(object):
   def __init__(self, bal=0):
       self.bal = bal
   def deposit(self, amount):
       self.bal+=amount
       print self.bal

def debit(self, amt):
   self.bal-=amt
   print self.bal

bank.debit = debit

myacct = bank() 
myacct.deposit(1000) # prints 1000
myacct.debit(99) # print 901

dir(myacct) # print [ ....'bal', 'debit', 'deposit']
```

then i used pickle and saved the object myacct

after saving, restarted my python and tried the commands below

```
>>> import pickle
>>> obj = pickle.load(open('bank.pkl'))
>>> dir(obj) # prints [....'bal', 'deposit']
```

note that 'debit' is not among the attributes . So my problem is how to make methods like 'debit' persistent?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  What's wrong with defining the `Bank` class properly to begin with?

Comment: As for getting back to add comments to a previous post, I suggest you register with StackOverflow so you have an account with associated questions.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `new` module (http://docs.python.org/library/new.html)

It has a lot of tools for doing things dynamically. The problem you are having is debit is not a instance method, it is just a normal function. Methods defined in classes are different than functions defined outside.

Comment: So using the `new` module will make it `pickle`?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the way `pickle` dumps custom classes.

```
>>> class Bank(object):
...     pass
...
>>> def debit(self, amt):
...     print amt
...
>>> Bank.debit = debit
>>>
>>> acct = Bank()
>>> acct.debit
<bound method Bank.debit of <__main__.Bank object at 0x023B57D0>>
>>> import pickle
```

Look at the following:

```
>>> print pickle.dumps(acct)
ccopy_reg
_reconstructor
p0
(c__main__
Bank
p1
c__builtin__
object
p2
Ntp3
Rp4
.
```

You'll see that in fact the entire instance isn't pickled; instead, `pickle` simply records that it is an instance of `Bank` and recreates it by re-instantiating `Bank`. You will have to define a custom pickle protocol if you want to do this properly, which is complicated.